# Pandas passing dataframe as a parameter , but variables are not getting proper values inside the function

Tags: python, pandas

```
numbers_1 = zero['_Mobile'].tolist()

def getmessage(number,df1):
    #get the points, gender and name... 
    message = 'Hello! Greetings from Royale Touche'
    try:
        name = df1.loc[df1['_Mobile'] == number,'Name'].tolist()[0]
        points = df1.loc[df1['_Mobile'] == number, 'Total_Credit_Points'].tolist()[0]
        gender = df1.loc[df1['_Mobile'] == number, 'Gender'].tolist()[0]

        print(gender)

        if gender.lower() == 'male':
            title = 'sir'

        else:
            title = 'mam'

        return message

    except:
        print("not found",number)

message = getmessage(numbers_1[I],zero)
```

Problem here is Gender is coming as Male for every iteration in the loop.. and its not changing to female. is there any bug in pandas?

Comment: can you show the head of the `dataframe`

Comment: In your code you don't have a loop, did you forget to copy-paste a part of your code iterating in a loop using the variable `I`? If you don't have a loop, `numbers_1[I]` is fixed so this is why you always have the same result.

Comment: As an aside, using a bare except (that wraps a ton of code no less) is a terrible practice. You may silence a bunch of errors you didn't intend to

Answer (score 0):

You most likely getting the same result because you hard coded `I` at the top of your code, so your always inputting the same variable

That being said here is a suggested update for your `getmessage` function

```
def getmessage(number, df1):
    name, points, gender = df1.loc[df1['_Mobile'] == number][['name', 'points', 
    'gender']].iloc[0].tolist()
    title = 'sir' if gender.lower() == 'male' else 'mam'
```